# Nested forms fields_for :prices, repeat forms few time

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, nested-attributes

i have many to many throught asociation and then i do this

```
fields_for :device
```

this displaying in good way, but i cannot save it i get unknown attribute :price
[image: fields_for :device]

And `fields_for :devices`

[image: field_for :devices]

And so on, one device makes one more repeat, if i write f`.fields_for :price` it gives good text field count, but it write

```
unknown attribute: price
Rails.root: C:/Users/Ignas/mildai/baze4

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/commercial_offers_controller.rb:74:in `block in update'
app/controllers/commercial_offers_controller.rb:73:in `update'
```

thank you

additional information:

controller

```
 def edit_prices
        @commercial_offer = CommercialOffer.find(params[:id])
     end
```

link to edit prices

```
  <%= link_to "Edit prices", :controller => "CommercialOffers", :action => "edit_prices", :id => @commercial_offer %>
```

_edit_price.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @commercial_offer do |f| %> 
        <% CommercialOffer.find(params[:id]).devices.each do |device| %>
            <%=  check_box_tag  "commercial_offer[device_ids][]", device.id, @commercial_offer.devices.include?(device) %>
                <%=  device.name %>         
            <%= f.fields_for :prices do |builder|  %>
                <%= render 'prices/new_price', :f => builder, :commercial_offer => @commercial_offer, :device => device %>
            <% end %>
         <% end %> 
            <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Save"%>
      </div>
    <% end %>
```

for one device it have render only one time, but it rendering for one device such times how many devices is with same commercial_offer_id

```
_new_price.html.erb
Price:
<%= f.text_field :price %></br>
Quantity:
<%= f.text_field :quantity %></br>
Device id:
<%= f.text_field :device_id, :value => device.id %></br>


class CommercialOffer < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :prices
has_many :devices, :through => :prices
accepts_nested_attributes_for :prices
accepts_nested_attributes_for :devices
end

class Device < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :prices
accepts_nested_attributes_for :prices
has_many :commercial_offer, :through => :prices

class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :device
    belongs_to :commercial_offer
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no any `field_for` method.

Also your question isn't clear. What actually you want to do? Show only one device? Wich one? First, last?

**UPD**

commercial_offer.rb:

```
class CommercialOffer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :prices
  has_many :devices, :through => :prices
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :prices
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :devices, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

Your view

```
<%= form_for @commercial_offer do |f| %> 
    <%= f.fields_for :devices do |device| %>
        <p>
          <%= device.check_box :_destroy %>
          <%= device.label "Destroy?" %>
        </p>
        <p>
          <%= device.text_field :name %>         
        </p>
        <%= device.fields_for :prices do |builder|  %>
           <%= render 'prices/new_price', :f => device %>
        <% end %>
     <% end %> 
   <% end %>
   <div class="actions">
     <%= f.submit "Save"%>
   </div>
<% end %>
```

_new_price partial

```
<%= f.text_field :price %></br>
Quantity:
<%= f.text_field :quantity %></br>
Device id:
<%= f.text_field :device_id %></br>
```

Comment: yes, i made an error. i have 3 tables, first commercial_offers with field name, second devices, with few field, like name, description, and last prices with commercial_offer_id, device_id, and price field, i selected some devices to commercial offer, they recorded in prices table, so i want to add price for all asociations, it almost working, but records in edit view are multiplicationing, if i have 2 devices in commercial offer i get 4 records in view if i have 3 i get 9 records in view

Comment: but when i am using fields_for :price, it gives me good count of fields, but it cannot save it

Comment: ok show your models and show your entire view. but I still don't understand you

Comment: undefined method `check_box' and it is rendering the same way, for one device many times as it have devices

Comment: I've forgotten equal `=` sign there

Comment: And I give up to inderstand what are you going to do :)

Comment: It does not repeating anymore. Thank you. the last thing undefined method `name' for #<ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x42eb5f0>
Extracted source (around line #3):

1: <%= form_for @commercial_offer do |f| %> 
2:  <%= f.fields_for :devices  do |device| %>
3:   <%=device.name %>
4:         <p>
5:    
6:

Comment: it should be `<%= device.text_field :name %> ` or `<%= device.object.name %>` if you don't need a form here